# socket hang up while calling another API internally from API

Tags: node.js, api, sockets, httprequest

I am working in Node JS. I am facing error when I am trying to call another API from one API. When I am trying to do it it gives me this error.

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:331:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

I am calling followig API.

```
router.
    post('/cancel_order',
        async function(req, res){
            request({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/orders/cancel',
                method: 'POST',
                form: {
                    order_id: req.body.order_id,
                    reason: "qweui",
                    comment: req.body.comment
                },
                headers: req.headers
            }, 
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('error',error);
                } else {
                    console.log('body', body);
                }
            });
        }
    );
```

But as you can see above I am calling another API internally "orders/cancel" using request package. But after calling main API it gives me "socket hang up" error.
Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the `async` before `function` on line 3.

Comment: still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The above error was coming because of some validation error. Means I was sending all fields which was required in other API which I was calling internally. But one key was not getting in other API. So I have done the needful. So now its solved. Thanks.